# Typewriter Text inside multicolumn

Tags: multicol, typewriter

I'm using multicols to show the content of a text file, however I need to use the `\ttfamily` font. As in `\texttt{}` but that doesn't allow line breaks.

Since is a very extensive file I don't want to use `\allowbreak` every time.

Tried putting `{\ttfamily}` in and out of the code but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion about how to show text without using multicols is appreciated as well, however my main issue is being able to use typewriter text in that part of my article.

Thank you.

This is what I've got:

```
\begin{multicols}{3}[
 Example Text.
 ]
A B C D E F G H I J 

A J


A B 7 0

A C 9 0

A D 7 0

A E 10 0

A F 7 0

A G 10 0

A H 6 0

A I 10 0

A J 5 0

B C 3 0

B D 3 0

B E 8 0

B F 4 0

B G 8 0

B H 2 0

B I 10 0
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Welcome! Given that this works by default, I can only assume you are doing something to make it not work which you haven't shown. Always post complete minimal examples which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue. Code fragments are OK in explanations but hopeless for reproducing problems and trying to solve them. You know to put the text in the group, as well, I assume i.e. `{\ttfamily whatever}`

Comment: `\ttfamily` after `]`? Not with braces, of course.

Comment: Works without braces and all that.

Comment: what was the actual problem solved?? (`\texttt` and `\ttfamily` both allow line breaking? even though an answer is accepted it may still be useful for the site if the question is clarified.

Comment: The post marked as an answer solved the problem. I simply didn't know how to use Typewriter Text without using \texttt. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @DavidMerinos you could use `\texttt` if you wanted. It makes no difference to the linebreaking.

Comment: If I try for example `\texttt{Something Here 
Something next line}` the compiler fails. Note that it is inside a `multicols`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem using `\ttfamily` in a `multicols` environment. This compares the default serif with the same text in typewriter:

[image: roman and typewriter]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}[
 Example Text.
 ]
A B C D E F G H I J

A J


A B 7 0

A C 9 0

A D 7 0

A E 10 0

A F 7 0

A G 10 0

A H 6 0

A I 10 0

A J 5 0

B C 3 0

B D 3 0

B E 8 0

B F 4 0

B G 8 0

B H 2 0

B I 10 0
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{3}[
 Example Text.
 ]
 \ttfamily
A B C D E F G H I J

A J


A B 7 0

A C 9 0

A D 7 0

A E 10 0

A F 7 0

A G 10 0

A H 6 0

A I 10 0

A J 5 0

B C 3 0

B D 3 0

B E 8 0

B F 4 0

B G 8 0

B H 2 0

B I 10 0
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

If you want to avoid paragraph indentation, you can set `\parindent` to `0pt` either within the `multicols` group or inside a group including the entire `multicols` environment so that the header is aligned to the left:

```
{\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{multicols}{3}[
 Example Text.
 ]
 \ttfamily
A B C D E F G H I J

A J


A B 7 0

A C 9 0

A D 7 0

A E 10 0

A F 7 0

A G 10 0

A H 6 0

A I 10 0

A J 5 0

B C 3 0

B D 3 0

B E 8 0

B F 4 0

B G 8 0

B H 2 0

B I 10 0
\end{multicols}}
```

[image: shifting alignments]